# Constrained variational calculus: Are we allowed to make use of the constraint before taking variations?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Suppose that we have a variational problem,

$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(\vec{x}(t),\vec{x}'(t),|\vec{x}(t)|)dt$

subject to the constraint:

$|\vec{x}|=1$

where $\vec{x}(t)=\left\{x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t) \right\}.$
Are we allowed to rewrite the integral as

$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(\vec{x}(t),\vec{{x}'}(t),1)dt$

and continue with the conventional variational calculus procedure with Lagrange multiplier (i.e., substituting the constraint before taking the variational derivatives) ?

Comment: You simply impose the constraint. It is straightforward.

Comment: @OccupyGezi Will there be any need for using Lagrange multiplier after imposing the constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $\Phi(x)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(\vec{x}(t),\vec{x}'(t),|\vec{x}(t)|)\,dt$ and $\Psi(x)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(\vec{x}(t),\vec{x}'(t),1)\,dt$. You are looking for $\inf_{x\in A} \Phi(x)$ where $A$ is the set of admissible functions $x$. The following claim hardly needs a proof: it is a tautology.

*Claim*: If $\Phi(x)=\Psi(x)$ for all $x\in A$, then $\inf_{A} \Phi=\inf_{A} \Psi$. Moreover, the set of extremals is the same: $\{x\in A: \Phi(x)=\inf_A \Phi\}$ is the same set as $\{x\in A: \Psi(x)=\inf_A \Psi\}$.

Therefore, you can work with $\Psi$ instead of $\Phi$.